# How to combine results from three tables where two tables might have multiple records matching the criteria

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

```
mysql> select * from contacts;
+------+------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+---
| c_id | c_username       | c_firstname | c_lastname |
+------+------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-| 
|    7 | lem              | black       | color  |

|   12 | lem              | red         | color  |
+------+------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+-

mysql> select * from phone_numbers;
+------+------+--------+--------------+
| p_id | c_id | p_type | p_number     |
+------+------+--------+--------------+
|    6 |    7 | h      | 9856743817   |
|   17 |   12 | h      | 2324323443   |
|   18 |   13 | h      | 980213748921 |
|   20 |   12 | w      | 7895643219   |
+------+------+--------+--------------+

mysql> select * from emails;
+------+--------+-----------------+------+
| c_id | e_type | e_email         | e_id |
+------+--------+-----------------+------+
|    7 | h      | black@flock.com |    8 |
|    7 | w      | sheep@flock.com |   16 |
+------+--------+-----------------+------+
```

the output that i expect (list of all contacts by username in this case lem):

```
| 7 | black color | 9856743817 | black@flock.com,sheep@flock.com |
| 12 | red color | 2324323443,7895643219 | NULL |
```

the output that i get:

```
mysql> select c.c_id, c.c_firstname, c.c_lastname, group_concat(e.e_email separator ',') as c_email, group_concat(p.p_number separator ',') as c_phone_no
 from contacts c left join emails e on e.c_id = c.c_id left join phone_numbers p on p.c_id = c.c_id where c.c_username = 'lem' order by c.c_id;
+------+-------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| c_id | c_firstname | c_lastname | c_email  | c_phone_no                                  |
+------+-------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+-
|    7 | black       | sheep     | black@flock.com,sheep@flock.com | 9856743817,9856743817,2324323443,7895643219 |
+------+-------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+-
```

Also if possible please explain how i got that output.

After applying stick-bit's solution:

```
+------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------+
| c_id | c_firstname | c_lastname | c_email | c_phone_no            |
+------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------+
|    7 | black       | sheep      | black@flock.com,sheep@flock.com | 9856743817,9856743817 |
```

Notice that the phone_no is repeating. It gives same results if i used **order by c.c_id**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause, so all the rows get aggregated.

```
SELECT c.c_id,
       c.c_firstname,
       c.c_lastname,
       group_concat(DISTINCT e.e_email SEPARATOR ',') c_email,
       group_concat(DISTINCT p.p_number SEPARATOR ',') c_phone_no
       FROM contacts c
            LEFT JOIN emails e
                      ON e.c_id = c.c_id
            LEFT JOIN phone_numbers p
                      ON p.c_id = c.c_id
       WHERE c.c_username = 'lem'
       GROUP BY c.c_id,
                c.c_firstname,
                c.c_lastname
       ORDER BY c.c_id;
```

Unfortunately older versions of MySQL or loosely configured ones allow it to have columns in the list of selected columns, that aren't in a `GROUP BY` clause or passed to an aggregation function. On other DBMS your query would have been invalid and you might have recognized the error.

Comment: Your query will give bad output when there are more than 1 linked record in both tables or full duplicate records in any table. Edit it to `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT field ...)`.

Comment: @akina it works now after using DISTINCT keyword

Comment: @pebble I'd recommend you to add `ORDER BY` clause to `GROUP_CONCAT` parameters too...

Comment: @akina after using order by and distinct i got the result